# does Oracle NoSQL DB Cloud Service have one dedicated API to simply check if a table exists or not?

Tags: oracle-nosql

I am using Oracle NoSQL Database Cloud Service, I am using the API to Create, modify and drop Tables and Indexes. Also to do CRUD operations on my table.

But I am wondering if there is a dedicated API to simply check if a table exists or not?

Answer (score 1):

Please call getTable() function. This functions retrieves static information about a table, including its provisioned througput, capacity and schema, in the form of TableResult. Dynamic information such as usage() is obtained using getTableUsage

if the table does not exist, it will return an exception.

Here an example in Node.js

```
try {
let resExistingTab = await client.getTable('THETABLE');
await client.forCompletion(resExistingTab);
console.log(' Table %s exists', resExistingTab.tableName);
console.log(' Table state: %s', resExistingTab.tableState.name);
let resTab = await client.getTable('UNKNOWNTABLE');
await client.forCompletion(resTab);
console.log(' Table %s exists', resTab.tableName);
console.log(' Table state: %s', resTab.tableState.name);

}
catch (e) {
console.log(e._errCode);
}
finally {
console.log("entering and leaving the finally block");
}
```

BTW, after reading a little bit more, You can also use Lists tables documented [here](https://oracle.github.io/nosql-node-sdk/NoSQLClient.html#listTables)

Below a snippet in node

```
  let varListTablesResult = await client.listTables();
  console.log(varListTablesResult);
```

Names are returned in alphabetical order to facilitate paging (seems to be case sensitive)